# Problem with deriving sum of squares of odd numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was trying to derive formula for the sum of squares of odd numbers and I believe I made a mistake in calculations. The problem is, I don't know what mistake.

So I started from the fact that:

$\ 1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+...+n^2=n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 $

Since it is a sum of squares of first n natural numbers I concluded that I can separate odd and even numbers in this way(I believe this is my mistake, but I don't understand why exactly I cannot do this):

$\ 1^2+3^2+5^2+7^2+...+(2n+1)^2 + 2^2+4^2+6^2+8^2+...+4n^2=n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 $

If we express $\ 2^2+4^2+6^2+8^2+...+4n^2$ as A and divide it by 4 we get:

$\ 1/4 * A=1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2+...+n^2$

I wanted to use this to insert A in my first expression(sum of squares of first n numbers), but obviously I get negative expression, since I just derived that sum of squares of even numbers A is 4 times bigger than sum of squares of first n natural numbers. This does not make sense.

So my question is, what exactly is wrong with my judgement?

Comment: In the second sum you sum up the squares upto $(2n+1)^2$, but you use the formula for the squares upto $n$

Comment: Perhaps you could try adding $(n+1)^2$ to the first sum on both sides and see what the algebra leads to...

Comment: @Peter, oh right... I should go to sleep probably.. Thank you so much!

Comment: What is the last term of your sum? It is unclear whether you're adding up to n^2 or 4n^2

Comment: I now understand what I was doing wrong. Thank you all and sorry for such stupid question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first equation should be
$$\ 1^2+3^2+5^2+7^2+...+(2n+1)^2 + 2^2+4^2+6^2+8^2+...+4n^2=(2n+1)(2n+2)(4n+3)/6$$
because the upper limit of the sum is $2n+1$

Comment: I want to check that I understand it correctly, do we state that the upper limit is (2n+1) because (2n+1)^2 > 4n^2?

Comment: It is the largest term on the left.  You have added up the squares of all the numbers from $1$ to $2n+1$

Comment: Understand. Thank you very much and sorry for such stupid questions

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't exactly say what you should do instead, but I do see an issue with the reasoning that I think might help.
In order to separate the even and odd terms, you need to know whether $n$ is even or odd.
That is, when you say:
$$1^2 + 3^2 + ... + (2n+1)^2 + 2^2 + 4^2 + ... + (2n)^2$$
we need to recognize that we're summing from $1$ to $2n+1$, not from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: Yes, I got it, thank you!